# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_intro_slider_example/home.dart' , The name 'Slide' isn't a class

Tags: flutter, dart

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_intro_slider_example/home.dart'.
The name 'Slide' isn't a class.
The method 'HomePage' isn't defined for the type '_IntroSliderPageState'.
Undefined class 'Slide'.
The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.

does anybody knows what's wrong with this dart code. I got this from [github](https://github.com/Rapid-Technology/flutter_intro_slider_example/blob/master/lib/intro_slider.dart)  paste directly. now showing this big error. also, refer this  [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvjsh6MX55U)

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_intro_slider_example/home.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/dot_animation_enum.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/intro_slider.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/slide_object.dart';

class IntroSliderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroSliderPageState createState() => _IntroSliderPageState();
}

class _IntroSliderPageState extends State<IntroSliderPage> {
  List<Slide> slides = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Hello Food!",
        description:
        "The easiest way to order food from your favorite restaurant!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/hamburger.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Movie Tickets",
        description: "Book movie tickets for your family and friends!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/movie.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Great Discounts",
        description: "Best discounts on every single service we offer!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/discount.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "World Travel",
        description: "Book tickets of any transportation and travel the world!",
        pathImage: "assets/images/travel.png",
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> renderListCustomTabs() {
    List<Widget> tabs = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      Slide currentSlide = slides[i];
      tabs.add(
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 160, top: 60),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    currentSlide.pathImage,
                    matchTextDirection: true,
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    currentSlide.title,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 30,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    currentSlide.description,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      height: 1.5,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return tabs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntroSlider(
      backgroundColorAllSlides: Colors.green[700],
      renderSkipBtn: Text("Skip"),
      renderNextBtn: Text(
        "Next",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[700]),
      ),
      renderDoneBtn: Text(
        "Done",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[700]),
      ),
      colorDoneBtn: Colors.white,
      colorActiveDot: Colors.white,
      sizeDot: 8.0,
      typeDotAnimation: dotSliderAnimation.SIZE_TRANSITION,
      listCustomTabs: this.renderListCustomTabs(),
      scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      shouldHideStatusBar: false,
      onDonePress: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Click on `get dependencies`

Comment: Try using ```flutter pub get``` . If the problem still persists, do ```flutter clean``` and run ```flutter pub get``` again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `flutter pub get` to Get all the dependencies.
If you are using `VS Code` then Go to `pubspec.yaml` and click on `Get Packages`
Or if using `Android Studio` then `Tools` > `Flutter` > `Flutter Pub Get` to solve this.

Found out more [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

Answer (score 0):

This code will run perfectly with the `intro_slider: ^2.3.4` package. You might have upgraded the package version. Use intro_slider: ^2.3.4 version and run `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter clean` to clear all builds. then run `flutter pub upgrade`
to upgrade any outdated dependency. at last run `flutter pub get`.